# How do you specifiy a Neumann (fixed flux normal to face) boundary condition in Fipy?

Tags: python, mesh, pde, fipy

How do I explicitly set the flux normal to a boundary face in a fipy mesh to be a specific value, without constraining components of flux within the face?

A Neumann boundary condition can be specified as: (1) fixed component of flux normal to a boundary face, or (2) as a complete specification of flux at the face. The default fipy condition is the former (value = 0), but the explicit method (faceGrad.constrain) is the latter. The issue can be understood by adding the following code to the end of the fipy [diffusion.mesh20x20](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/diffusion/generated/examples.diffusion.mesh20x20.html) example and noting different face gradient results.

```
facesNeumann = mesh.exteriorFaces & ~facesTopLeft & ~facesBottomRight
print 'grad(phi) with default Neumann BC...'
print phi.faceGrad.value.T[facesNeumann.value]
phi.faceGrad.constrain(0.,facesNeumann)
DiffusionTerm().solve(var=phi)
print 'and with explicit Neumann BC...'
print phi.faceGrad.value.T[facesNeumann.value]
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see the discussion on [fixed flux boundary conditions](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/USAGE.html#applying-fixed-flux-boundary-conditions). Basically, you add a source containing the the divergence of the desired boundary flux to FiPy's default no-flux condition.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of just specifying the flux normal to a boundary for a variable independent of solving an equation, there does not appear to be any way to do that. The syntax might be `phi.faceGrad[0].constrain(...)` for example, but that currently doesn't work in FiPy. It might also be difficult to implement for arbitrary oriented faces.

However, for practical purposes, the component tangential to a boundary is not used when solving an equation in FiPy, only the normal component has any influence on the solution. For example, take the following code,

```
import fipy as fp
mesh = fp.Grid2D(nx=2, ny=1)
var = fp.CellVariable(mesh=mesh)
var.constrain(1, mesh.facesLeft)
var.constrain(0, mesh.facesRight)
#var.faceGrad.constrain(0, mesh.facesTop)
fp.DiffusionTerm().solve(var)
print 'face gradient on top plane:',var.faceGrad[0, mesh.facesTop.value]
print 'variable value:',var
```

This gives an output of

```
face gradient on top plane: [-0.5 -0.5]
variable value: [ 0.75  0.25]
```

The answer is correct, but the top face gradient is -0.5. However, when the line `#var.faceGrad.constrain(0, mesh.facesTop)` is uncommented, the result is

```
face gradient on top plane: [ 0.  0.]
variable value: [ 0.75  0.25]
```

The tangential face gradient is now 0, but the answer is the same. The point is that setting the face gradient tangentially (via `.constrain`) has no influence on the solution.

Comment: What if you wanted one boundary condition to depend on the magnitude of the gradient of another and as such only wanted to set the normal component. Say, `phi1.constrain(fp.numerix.dot(phi2.faceGrad, phi2.faceGrad))` where we want to specify only the normal component of `phi2` on the boundary. Does this answer mean doing so wouldn't work? (I don't have a good example, just curious). Maybe @jeguyer's answer is appropriate in that case?

Comment: @muon; I think that the constraint method fails for most arbitrary complex interdependent boundary conditions and the source term method is required (@jeguyer answer).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The discussion on fixed flux boundary conditions does answer my question, but I had not understood the documentation, which is very brief. Below is a worked example that illustrates how to apply this in a simple 2D case, similar to the mesh20x20 example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from fipy import *

nx = 20
ny = nx
dx = 1.
dy = dx
L = dx * nx
msh = Grid2D(dx=dx, dy=dy, nx=nx, ny=ny)

xFace, yFace = msh.faceCenters
xCell,yCell = msh.cellCenters    
phi = CellVariable(name = "solution variable",
                   mesh = msh,
                   value = 0.)    
D = FaceVariable(name='diffusion coefficient',mesh=msh,value=1.)

# Dirichlet condition on top face
valueTop = FaceVariable(name='valueTop',mesh=msh,value=xFace*0.1-1)
phi.constrain(valueTop, msh.facesTop)

# Fixed flux (Neumann) on base
D.constrain(0., msh.facesBottom)
fluxBottom = -0.05

eq = DiffusionTerm(coeff=D) + (msh.facesBottom * fluxBottom).divergence
eq.solve(var=phi)

# confirm only y component of gradient is zero
print phi.faceGrad.value.T[msh.facesBottom.value]

plt.scatter(phi.value, yCell)
plt.show()

viewer = Viewer(vars=phi, datamin=-1., datamax=1.)
viewer.plot()
```